# react native remote debug on chrome not working

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I fallowed this [site](https://www.sitepoint.com/tools-for-debugging-react-native/) to enable remote debug on chrome, but chrome is always showing `Status: Another debugger is already connected` I dont understand why. I only have one tab open and on the android emulator I have clicked `control + shift + m` and clicked on debug and now it shows stop debugging.

So what I'm I doing wrong ?

Comment: You might have another chrome tab that already debugger is running.

Comment: I dont have that, i already wrote that up